# Aldon and CVTRPGSRC from RPGIII to RPGIV

Tags: version-control, ibm-midrange, rpgle, rpg

I have a program that I want to convert from RPGIII to RPGIV.  I cannot figure out how to get ALDON to do it. I am on release 7.5E on the iSeries (green screen).

I have converted the source outside of ALDON and within ALDON I have changed the check out object (option 16) from RPG to RPGLE extended attribute of BND.  This will work, however, the source is still in QRPGSRC physical source file (92 columns) rather than QRPGLESRC(112 columns).  I've effectively lost any comments that might have been in the original source.  Option 16 in ALDON doesn't allow you to change the source file.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option 9 in ALDON allows you to move the source to a new file. It can then be changed with option 16.

Comment: Thank you, that's what I couldn't find.

Answer (score 1):

It's been awhile since I've coded in RPG, and I'm not sure if this will work in your development environment.

I always created a new file QRPGLESRC and set it to 112 record length, then just copy all the members from QRPGSRC to QRPGLESRC and then run your conversion tool over that.

I vaguely remember the command CPYSRCMBR, you should be able to type that in on the command line with a question mark in front i.e. ?CPYSRCMBR to prompt all the default options - each iSeries is setup with different defaults.

However, be sure and check to make sure your actual code is there and not just the member names (i.e. program names). I burned myself like this once and I had to go back to tape to get my code.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  CVTRPGSRC command is used to convert the source.  My issue is with ALDON.  Once the object is created in ALDON, it doesn't appear that they allow you to change the source file that you originally assigned to store the source.

Answer (score 0):

```
•   Use CVTRPGSRC to convert from RPG to RPGLE.
•   Rename the source member in RPGLE
•   From ACMS find the object converted, as it will still be on record as an RPG program.
•   Select the object with an option 9.
•   Change the ‘To Source member’ from *SAME to QRPGLESRC
•   Select the object with an option 16 to change. Change the Object attribute to RPGLE, and the Extended attribute to BND.
•   At this point, the member should be in your correct, QRPGLESRC file. Delete it and rename the member name back to its original name.
```